# Issue in DIV Positioning when Zoomed

Tags: html, css, web

Please have a look at the below code

**Index5.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="styles/cssmenu/menu_source/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="styles/cssmenu2/cssmenu/menu_source/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="main"> 
  <!------------------------ start menu bar ------------------------->
  <div class="menu_bar">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
      <ul>
        <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>MAIN PAGE</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>ABOUT US</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>VIDEO SAMPLES</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>PACKAGES</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>FAQS</span></a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>CONTACTS</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end menu_bar --> 

  <!------------------------ start body_container ------------------------->
  <div class="body_container2">
    <!------------------------ start block_left ------------------------->
    <div class="block_left4" >
      <div class="logo_container"><img src="images/LOGO4.gif" width="740" height="638"/></div>
    </div>
    <!-- end block_left -->
    <!------------------------ start video_container ------------------------->
    <div class="video_container2">
      <!------------------------ start video ------------------------->
      <div class="video1">
        <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="550" height="300" data-setup="{}" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" preload="none" controls>
          <source type="video/mp4" src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4"></source>
          <source type="video/webm" src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm"></source>
          <source type="video/ogg" src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv"></source>
          <track label="English" srclang="en" src="demo.captions.vtt" kind="captions"></track>
          <!--Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
          <track label="English" srclang="en" src="demo.captions.vtt" kind="subtitles"></track>
          <!--Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
        </video>
      </div>
      <!-- end video -->
      <!------------------------ start div_bottom_video ------------------------->
      <div class="div_bottom_video"> <a href=""><span  id="last2">Menu</span></a> <a href=""><span>Sound</span></a> <a href=""><span>Mail</span></a></div>
      <!-- end div_bottom_video -->
    </div>
    <!-- end video_container -->
    <!------------------------ start presentation_container ------------------------->
    <!-- end presentation_container -->
    <!------------------------ start block_container ------------------------->
    <div class="block_container3">
      <!------------------------ start block1 ------------------------->
      <div class="block1_1">
        <h3>PRICES</h3>
        <ul>
          <a href="">
            <li>Cicerd</li>
          </a> <a href="">
              <li>Cicero (en)</li>
              </a> <a href="">
                <li>Li Europan lingues</li>
                </a> <a href="">
                  <li>beatae vitae </li>
                  </a>
        </ul>
        <hr align="center" width="100%" color="#CCCCCC"/>
        <ul>
          <a href="">
            <li>Neque porro quisquam</li>
          </a> <a href="">
              <li>voluptas nulla </li>
              </a> <a href="">
                <li>placeat facere</li>
                </a> <a href="">
                  <li>laboriosam</li>
                  </a> <a href="">
                    <li>dolorem</li>
                    </a> <a href="">
                      <li>omnis iste</li>
                      </a> <a href="">
                        <li>fugit</li>
                        </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end block1 -->
      <!------------------------ start block2 ------------------------->
      <div class="block2_1">
        <h3>WHO WE ARE</h3>
        <div class="image_box"></div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. </p>
        <div class="link"><a href="">Click here</a></div>
      </div>
      <!-- end block2 -->
    </div>
    <!-- end block_container -->
  </div>
  <!-- end body_container --> 
  <!------------------------ start footer ------------------------->
  <div class="footer">
    <div id='cssmenu2'>
      <ul>
        <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Main Page</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>About Us</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Video Samples</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Packages</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Faqs</span></a></li>
        <li id='last'><a href='#'><span id="last">Contacts</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <p><span id="format">DIETBYDNA</span> @ 2008 <a href="">privacy policy</a></p>
  </div>
  <!-- end footer --> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* styles on index.html */
h3 {
    color: #609;
}
.main {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background-image: url(../images/background6.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.menu_bar {
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    width: 900px;
    padding: 0px 50px 10px 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.body_container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 30px 20px 0px 20px;
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.body_container2 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 00px 20px 0px 20px;
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}


/*******************************/
.block_left {
    margin-top: 70px;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;

}

.block_left1 {

    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;

}

.block_left2 {

    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;

}

.block_left3 {

    float: left;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;

}

.block_left4 {

    float: left;
    width: 740px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;

}
.logo_container {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
/*******************************/
.video_container {
    margin-top: 70px;
    float: right;
    width: 550px;
    height: 340px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.video_container1 {
    margin-top: 70px;
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.video_container2 {
    margin-top: 70px;
    float: right;
    width: 550px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    left: 327px;
    top: 194px;
}
.video {
    width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid thin #999;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #666;
}

.video1 {
    width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid thin #999;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #666;
}
.example_video_1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.div_bottom_video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.div_bottom_video span {
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-right: #CCC thin solid;
    color: #609;
}
.div_bottom_video #last {
    border-right: none;
}
.div_bottom_video img {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.div_bottom_video a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.div_bottom_video a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/*******************************/
.presentation_container {
    float: right;
    width: 590px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.presentation_container1 {
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.presentation_container2 {

    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 550px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;

}

.presentation_container3 {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 550px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position:absolute;
    left: 500px;
    top: 679px;

}
/*******************************/
.block_container {
    background-color: #666;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 550px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.block_container1 {
    background-color: #666;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.block_container2 {
    background-color: #666;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 550px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.block_container3 {
    background-color: #666;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    float: right;
    clear:both;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);

}


.block1 {
    float: right;
    width: 235px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    clear: both;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.block1_1 {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    clear: both;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.block1 li {
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.block1 a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style: url(../images/bullet.png);
}
.block1 a:hover {
    color: #036;
}
.block2 {
    float: right;
    width: 235px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;

}

.block2_1 {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;

}
.image_box {
    background-image: url(../images/image4.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border: solid #333 thin;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
/*******************************/
.footer {
    height: 80px;
    width: 900px;
    padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.footer p {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.footer a {
    color: #333;
}
.footer #format {
    color: #09F;
    font-size: 14px;
}
/*******************************/
.link {
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 91px;
    height: 28px;
    background: url("http://dabuttonfactory.com/b.png?t=click%20here&f=Calibri&ts=15&tc=ffffff00&tshs=1&tshc=22222200&it=png&c=7&bgt=gradient&bgc=a27de3&ebgc=471870&be=on&hp=17&vp=9") no-repeat;
    line-height: 28px;
    vertical-align: text-middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-shadow: #222222 1px 1px 0;
}
.link a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.link a:hover {
    color: #CCC;
}
```

This code generates the below web page.

[image]

As you can see, the Video container is not positioned well, some part of it is positioned outside the page! I also noticed when I zoom-in or zoom-out, the position of the video container changes!

I need the video container near to the logo in left side and it should not move here and there when I zoom-in or zoom-up. Video container starts with the below code

```
 <!------------------------ start video_container ------------------------->
    <div class="video_container2">
```

How can make this happen?

Comment: I'll upvote the person who'll take the time to research and solve your problem but just my 2-cent would be to try overflow:hidden on the container element.

Comment: @frenchie: Hi, I am not a web designer, so what is the container element? I added the thing you asked to the `.video_container2` but still no good.

Comment: @frenchie: I believe `position:relative` will solve the case, but it places the video in somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the fixed width of the container you can use Bootstrap and its "col" class  to make it responsive

Answer (score 0):

In your css class `.videocontainer2` , you have added `float:right` that's why it is positioned on the right side. So either add `margin-right://value in pix` property keeping `float:right` or add `margin-left://value in pix` property and remove `float:right`.

To keep the position of your div tag fixed, you can do it by adding `position:fixed` property in your css class `.videocontainer2`

Answer (score 0):

your '.videocontainer2' has 'position:absolute' and 'float:right'.. these are two different ways of positioning an element..

I'm not going to track all your positioning rules but try this:

```
.video_container2 {
    margin-top: 70px;
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

notice I've removed your 'absolute' positioning and also changed 'float' to 'left';

if you have a link to your page, than helping you would be much much easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But this code brought the video down of the logo. and I am sorry, site is not hosted yet.

Comment: what is the wanted behavior? you want the video to go to the right of the logo?

Comment: by the page layout, I assumed the video should be placed under the logo, the right of the logo seems to be out of screen.. no?

Comment: Yes, video to the right of the logo. what you see here is a zoomed-out image. That is why it is out of screen.

Comment: @Hope In general, working with such layouts in 'pixels' are not easily auto adjusted to 'browser zoom'.. does your page look as it's supposed to without the zoom?

Comment: so... basically your problem only happens in ZOOM? you should update your question so it'll be more clear.. write that in the title for example..